# Emmet в Visual Studio Code

Tags: frontend, emmet, visual-studio-code

Установил Visual Studio Code, всё полностью устраивает кроме того, как работает встроенный Emmet, когда я набираю db аббревиатура разворачивается не в display: block, а в box-decoration-break, и так со многими другими аббревиатурами, как сделать чтобы всё было как обычно?

Answer (score 0):

Просто у вас срабатывает на tab сразу 2 действия. Emmet и подсказка кода. Отключите подсказку кода или же нажимайте экспейп, чтоб отменить подсказку кода, а потом tab для эммета.